# Как внешний класс объявить другом внутреннего? С++

Tags: c++

Внутренний (вложенный класс) содержит private данные, как правильно объявить внешний другом, чтоб получить к ним доступ?

```
using namespace std;


class hen
{
public:
class nest   
friend class hen;
{};            
};

int main()
{   
hen first;
hen::nest second;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибки типа:

*9  class hen is implicitly friends with itself*

*16  nest is not a member of hen*

Comment: Добавил код, @Harry, можете посмотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Как обычно - с ключевым словом `friend`:

```
class Test {
public:
    class Inner
    {
        // Чтобы работало - раскомментируйте следующую строку:
        // friend class Test;
    public:
        Inner(int val):val_(val){}
        private:
        int val_;
    };
    int get(Inner&i) { return i.val_; }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t;
    Test::Inner r(3);
    t.get(r);

}
```

P.S. В связи с обновленным вами вопросом:

```
class hen
{
public:
class nest   
friend class hen;
{};            
};
```

запишите правильно - как

```
class hen
{
public:
    class nest   
    {
        friend class hen;
    };            
};
```

Обратите также внимание, насколько понятнее записанное при правильных отступах...